# Checking for existing file in C drive and then running an installer for batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I`m trying to code a batch file that checks whether a file exists in my c drive.
If it exists , it will end the batch file.
if not, it will run an MSI file.

I got it to run the MSI file , however after installing it.
The checks do not work and it keeps prompting me to install the file.

I have attached the code that i have written.
And also is there any way to do a slient install of MSI in batch? 
May i know what is wrong with the code?

```
if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\hi.txt" goto END
msiexec /i "\\computer-name\Test\setup.msi" 
:END
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `:END` on its own line?

Comment: Hi tripp,
sorry missed a space there.
It is already on a new line

Comment: Does the installer create the file `hi.txt` at exactly that place?

Comment: Hi thomas,
no, this batch will first check whether hi.txt exists.
If it does not, it will run setup.msi
It it does, it will just go to end

Comment: The question above is: does the file exist in that folder.  If it doesn't then it will launch the executable again.

Comment: Hi Foxidrive,
yes that is correct. Sorry if the title is misleading.
the files were in my c drive, however the installer kicks in still.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the silent install by typing `>nul` after `msiexec /i "\\computer-name\Test\setup.msi"`

So, it would look like this:

```
msiexec /i "\\computer-name\Test\setup.msi">nul
```

This works on my computer, I hope it works for you too :)